# C# Custom URI Scheme - not working when URI Length too long

Tags: c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer, encoding, uri

I want to generate a link, and whenever the link is clicked, my application will open and do stuff with the parameters.
The parameters are transferred as JSON and encoded in base64.
eventually, I get something like that:

> myapp://LocalStuff/DoStuff?Args=**JSON_IN_BASE64_TEXT**

and it is working for most cases. But when JSON_IN_BASE64_TEXT is too long it doesn't do anything.

When its not too long (under 1000 chars) it works in IE 11 and Chrome.

Under 2000 chars it works in Chrome but not in IE 11.

Over 2000 or so it doesn't work in IE 11 nor Chrome.

Any suggestions to solve this URI length problem?

Comment: Shift from using GET to POST. GET is limited in size, whereas POST sizes are much much larger.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and there is no way to make it work with long urls. But there are always the workarounds. You can try the following:

1. You can generate some short random string (GUID) and pass it in url
2. Your application opens url and retrieve all arguments from the server with this GUID.

Comment: I want my users to be able to write their own URLs and publish it, and when other users will click on it my application will know how to handle it.